# Find out which encoding method less uses to display the content of a text file?

Tags: character-encoding, less

There is a plain text file, which Emacs can't display correctly, but `less` can.

I wonder if `less` automatically detects the encoding method for each individual text file, or just use a single default encoding method for all text files?

How can I find out the encoding method `less` uses to decode a text file?

Answer (score 6):

The `less` executable itself does not do any encoding conversion: it sends the printable characters directly to the terminal. What is regarded as printable is controlled by the `LESSCHARSET` environment variable (see the man page for details), but in general, you do not want to touch that. So, basically, the encoding is obtained from the locales (except with particular settings).

The input can be filtered, in particular to do a conversion, if the `LESSOPEN` environment variable is set. The corresponding filter can tell you whether it has done some conversion; this is what Wolfgang Friebel's `lesspipe` does, for instance.

You can use the `file` utility to get the encoding. For instance:

```
$ file my_file.txt
my_file.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

This is probably better than relying on `less`.

Answer (score 3):

`less` will use UTF-8 on most today's system. From `man less`:

> ```
> If neither LESSCHARSET nor LESSCHARDEF is set, but any of the strings
> "UTF-8", "UTF8", "utf-8" or "utf8" is found in the LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE or
> LANG environment variables, then the default character set is utf-8.
>
> If that string is not found, but your system supports the setlocale
> interface, less will use setlocale to determine the character set.
> setlocale is controlled by setting the LANG or LC_CTYPE environment
> variables.
>
> Finally, if the setlocale interface is also not available, the default
> character set is latin1.
> ```

To make sure that `less` works this way create a file with the following contents:

> ąśćã

Print it with `less`. If all characters are displayed correctly, that means your `LANG` contains UTF-8. See it with `locale` command or print `$LANG` variable. Now change your locale to something without UTF-8 in name, for
example:

```
$ export LANG=en_US
```

Print this file again. Unicode characters shouldn't be printed correctly.

I also use Emacs and I remember some situations when it couldn't display files correctly but `less` could.